# yum update failed on amazon linux2 after installing php56 with repo "repo.ius.io"

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux-2

on **amazonlinux2** i have installed php56 with repo **ius-release** for nginx webapplicaion.

```
 sudo yum -y update
    sudo yum install –y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
    wget https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el7.rpm
    sudo rpm -Uvh ius-release*.rpm
    sudo yum -y update
    sudo yum install --enablerepo=ius-archive php56u php56u-opcache php56u-xml php56u-mcrypt php56u-gd php56u-devel php56u-mysql php56u-intl php56u-mbstring php56u-bcmath php56u-soap
```

Reference URL for  php56 installation : https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=284157

Now I am getting the below error for  "#yum update -y", either I am looking for an alternate way to install php5.6 on amazon linux2 or a solution on the below error.

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php56u-pecl-imagick-3.4.3-1.ius.el7.x86_64 (@ius-archive)
           Requires: libMagickWand.so.5()(64bit)
           Removing: ImageMagick-6.7.8.9-15.amzn2.0.2.x86_64 (@amzn2-core)
               libMagickWand.so.5()(64bit)
           Updated By: ImageMagick-6.9.10.68-5.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               Not found
           Available: ImageMagick-6.7.8.9-15.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               libMagickWand.so.5()(64bit)
           Available: ImageMagick-6.7.8.9-18.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               libMagickWand.so.5()(64bit)
           Available: ImageMagick-6.9.10.68-3.amzn2.0.1.i686 (amzn2-core)
               Not found
Error: Package: php56u-pecl-imagick-3.4.3-1.ius.el7.x86_64 (@ius-archive)
           Requires: libMagickCore.so.5()(64bit)
           Removing: ImageMagick-6.7.8.9-15.amzn2.0.2.x86_64 (@amzn2-core)
               libMagickCore.so.5()(64bit)
           Updated By: ImageMagick-6.9.10.68-5.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               Not found
           Available: ImageMagick-6.7.8.9-15.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               libMagickCore.so.5()(64bit)
           Available: ImageMagick-6.7.8.9-18.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               libMagickCore.so.5()(64bit)
           Available: ImageMagick-6.9.10.68-3.amzn2.0.1.i686 (amzn2-core)
               Not found
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Why do you need AL2? Use AL1 or Ubuntu or anything that naturally supports php 5.6.

Comment: @Marcin New-Relic Laravel package is not compatible with amazon linux1.

Comment: @Marcin below is installation log of New-Relic
==> Installing infrastructure-agent-installer...success.

==> Installing logs-integration...
Logging is not supported on this version of Amazon Linux.
==> Installing logs-integration...failed.